# Correctly killing newly spawned isolates

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I am aware of the fact that when both microtask and event queues of an isolate are empty, the isolate is killed. However, I'm not able to find a reference on the documentation of how a worker isolate can be killed under certain circumstances.

---

**Context**

Let's make this example:

```dart
Future<void> main() {
  final receivePort = ReceivePort();
  final worker = await Isolate.spawn<SendPort>((_) {}, receivePort.sendPort);

  await runMyProgram(receivePort, worker);
}
```

Here the main isolate is creating a new one (`worker`) and then the program starts doing stuff.

---

**Question**

How do I manually kill the newly spawned isolate when it's not needed anymore? I wasn't able to explicitly find this information on the documentation so I am kind of guessing. Do I have to do this?

```dart
 receivePort.close();
 worker.kill();
```

Or is it enough to just close the port, like this?

```dart
  receivePort.close();
```

---

**Note**

I thought about this. If the worker isolate has both queues (microtask and event) empty and I close the receive port, it should be killed automatically. If this is the case, calling `receivePort.close()` should be enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kill an isolate from the outside, using the [`Isolate.kill`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/kill.html) method on an `Isolate` object representing that isolate.
(That's why you should be careful about giving away such isolate objects, and why you can create an isolate object without the "kill" capability, that you can more safely pass around.)

You can immediately kill an isolate from the inside using the static [`Isolate.exit`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/exit.html).
Or using `Isolate.current.kill`. It's like [`Process.exit`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/exit.html), but only for a single isolate.

Or you can make sure you have closed every open receive port in the isolate, and stopped doing anything.
That's the usual approach, but it can fail if you run code provided by others in your isolate. They might open receive ports or start periodic timers which run forever, and that you know nothing about.
(You can try to contain that code in a [`Zone`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Zone-class.html) where you control timers, but that won't stop them from creating receive ports, and they can always access [`Zone.root`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Zone/root-constant.html) directly to leave the zone you put them in.)
Or someone might have [Isolate.pause](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/pause.html)ed your isolate, so the worker code won't run.

---

If I wanted to be *absolutely certain* that an isolate is killed,
I'd start out by communicating with my own code running in that isolate (the port receiving worker instructions) and tell it to shut down nicely, as a part of the protocol I am already using to communicate.
The worker code can choose to use `Isolate.exit` when it's done, or just close all its own resources and hope it's enough. I'd probably tend to use `Isolate.exit`, but only after waiting for existing worker tasks getting done.
Such a worker task might be hanging (waiting for a future which will never complete). Or it might be live-locking everything by being stuck in a `while (true){..can't stop, won't stop!..}`. In that case, the waiting should have a timeout.

Because of that, I'd also listen for the isolate to shut down, using [`Isolate.addOnExitHandler`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/addOnExitListener.html), and start a timer for some reasonable duration, and if I haven't received an "on exit" notification before the timer runs out, or some feedback on the worker shutdown request telling me that things are fine, I'd escalate to `isolate.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate);` which can kill even a `while (true) ...` loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure the child isolate shuts down, even if it's in the middle of doing something, you'll want to call [`Isolate.kill()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.5/dart-isolate/Isolate/kill.html).

However, as you've already pointed out, an isolate will exit on its own if it has no more events to process and it holds no open ports (e.g., timers, open sockets, isolate ports, etc). For most cases, this is the ideal way to dispose of an isolate when it's no longer used since it eliminates the risk of killing the isolate while it's in the middle of doing something important.

Assuming your child isolate is good about cleaning up its own open ports when it's done doing what it needs to do, `receivePort.close()` should be enough for you to let it shut down.

Comment: To clarify, also note that doing `receivePort.close()` does not contribute to the worker isolate shutting down - that is just about the main isolate properly closing its resources. The spawned isolate only sees a `SendPort` and has no way of knowing when the corresponding `ReceivePort` closes.

Comment: Good point, `receivePort` doesn't contribute to the list of open ports in the worker isolate, but don't forget to call `receivePort.close()` if you want the parent isolate to shutdown gracefully at some point.